# @JoinColumns and JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

i have been a while trying to solve me problem but realy i can't...

The problem is that when i make a JPA (generated by Netbeans) i find lot of problems for exemple:

I have  : **Class USER** :

```
public class User implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
protected UserPK userPK;
...
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userList")
private List<Meeting> meetingList;

@JoinTable(name = "contact", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER2", referencedColumnName = "ID_USER")},              inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER", referencedColumnName = "ID_USER")})

@ManyToMany
private List<User> userList;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userList")
private List<User> userList1;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idUser")
private List<Invitation> invitationList;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idUser")
private List<Coordonnees> coordonneesList;
...
}
```

**Class Invitation**

```
public class Invitation implements Serializable {
...
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER", referencedColumnName = "ID_USER")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private User idUser;
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_MEETING", referencedColumnName = "ID_MEETING")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Meeting idMeeting;
...
}
```

**Class meeting**

```
public class Meeting implements Serializable {
...
@JoinTable(name = "user_meeting", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_MEETING", referencedColumnName = "ID_MEETING")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER", referencedColumnName = "ID_USER")})
@ManyToMany
private List<User> userList;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idMeeting")
private List<Invitation> invitationList;
...
}
```

**Class Coordonnees**

```
public class Coordonnees implements Serializable {
...
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER", referencedColumnName = "ID_USER")
@ManyToOne
private User idUser;
...
}
```

And when i deploy my project i find lot of problems like :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse  Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [GpsPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field idUser] from the entity class [class Jpa_gps.Coordonnees] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using  the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in  each such @JoinColumn.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1950)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1941)
...
```

Comment: You should give more information about domain model. I simply don't rely on auto generated code. And one more think you have two user list (userList, userList1) in User entity which I don't know what the purpose of these two.

Comment: The error tells you the problem- User has a composite primary key (ID_MEETING and Id_USER), so the Coordonness reference to it also needs two foreign keys.  Check out the meeting to user reference.  You might want to make User have a single field id to make life easier